# Choose a and b lists from 1 list but a and b values arent same

Tags: python, list

I have a question ,I have one list :
country = [ Australia , america , England , Spain]
If i want to choose 2 of them random for (List A) and choose 2 of them random for (List B ) and values of two lists arent same (not equal to  gether)
Can You say which code should i write

Comment: [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) four items and then split them into two lists…

Comment: `pairings = list(itertools.zip_longest(*[iter(random.sample(country, k=len(country)))] * 2))`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample):

```
country = ['Australia', 'america', 'England', 'Spain']

import random
random.sample(country, k=2)
```

If you want to split in two:

```
A = set(country)
B = random.sample(A, k=2)
A = list(A.difference(B))
```

output:

```
>>> A
['England', 'america']

>>> B
['Spain', 'Australia']
```

###### alternative: [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) (modifies the initial list)

```
import random
random.shuffle(country)
A = country[:2]
B = country[2:]
```

Comment: alternative: [`random.sample(country, k=len(country))`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) (doesn't modify the initial list)

Comment: @Olvin, yes so many possibilities ;) the downside is that it makes a copy.

Comment: I'd say it's a pros of it *(if initial data modification is not allowed)*

Comment: @Olvin Roght that would give you the same list as the original (4 entries) but shuffled. Why would that be of use in this scenario?

Comment: @Marc-AlexandruBaetica what Olvin suggested was just to replace the `shuffle`, then you still need to split in two ;)

Comment: Gotcha. Seemed like he was talking about the `random.sample()` from the second example. Thanks for the clarification :)

Comment: Passing a set to random.sample has been deprecated since python-3.9.

Comment: @ekhumoro I didn't know that, thanks for the tip

Answer (score -1):

If I got you right, this could help

```py
l = ['Australia' , 'america' , 'England' , 'Spain']

a = random.choices(l,k=2)
b=[]
for i in l:
    if(i not in a):
        b.append(i)
print(a)
print(b)
```

you can also try using sets